# internet explorer 8 background colour wrapping underneath

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, background

So I've set the body background-color for a webpage to be a solid colour and i've made the content div which contains all of the content have a different background colour and have a smaller width but a height of 100% (i've previously set the html and body height and width to 100%). In chrome, firefox and IE10 it works how i want it to with two columns of colour on either side and a white box in the middle where the content is. In IE8 however, background colour is also visible underneath the content so that the background colour forms a sort of U around the content which is not what I want. Any ideas?

```
body, html{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Corbel;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: normal;
    background-color: #d5e6c7;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 940px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Here is some of the css code, not sure if there are any other parts of the code you would need to look at. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this error with the css given and only these two elements. Perhabs some other css is messing something up?

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm thinking... Can't seem to find it though... Really quite annoying. Is there any type of override or something that will make sure an element goes the full height of the page regardless of anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looking at the template the layout goes like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="templatemo_body_wrapper">
        <div id="templatemo_wrapper">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="templatemo_footer_wrapper">
        <!-- footer -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So it looks like you'll need the good old padding + negative margin hack/trick/thing if you really need this exact behavior with that layout.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#templatemo_body_wrapper, #templatemo_wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
#templatemo_body_wrapper { overflow: hidden; }
#templatemo_wrapper {
    padding: 0 10px 2050px 10px !important;
    margin: 0 auto -2000px auto !important;
}
```

Seems to work in IE8 for me. Try it out.

#### Original Response

I'm not able to reproduce the problem you describe.

However, you might want to check that you have declared a DOCTYPE at the top of your HTML document, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Not doing so will send IE into [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

I tried rendering the page without a DOCTYPE to trigger Quirks Mode and it caused the white section to no longer be centered. Not sure if this is the issue you are describing or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have declared the doctype and the white section is still centred... it must be something else. I was given the website using a template so it's got a lot of unnecessary code in it. The template is called templatemo 304 light grey i think

Comment: Alright. Just from doing a Google search for that, I found [this](http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_304_light_gray), which seems like the right one. I know how to fix it. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot for this. That appears to have made the area of green on the bottom smaller but it is still there... Something funky must be going on.

Comment: If i remove all the content from the page except for a bunch of linebreaks and a single sentence (so that the page still needs to scroll) then it works fine... Any idea what that means?

Comment: Okay. I removed the footer element while I was testing it. Whoops! My latest edit seems to be working. Hopefully I nailed it this time.